# What's the point of Semaphore.drainPermits()?

Tags: java, concurrency

public int drainPermits():

> Acquires and returns all permits that are immediately available. Returns: the number of permits acquired.

Why would someone want to acquire and then immediately release all available permits from a Semaphore? If they want to see the number of available permits, why not use `Semaphore.availablePermits()`?

Comment: It doesn't return them to the semaphore after acquiring them, but as a count to the caller of the function (via the return parameter). It's worded confusingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't release them. It acquires them all, that's all:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(10);
System.out.println(s.availablePermits()); // 10
s.drainPermits();
System.out.println(s.availablePermits()); // 0
```